# Gridview RowCommand arguments not passing correctly in Safari

Tags: asp.net, gridview, rowcommand

I have an asp page with a gridview on. I have also added a clientscript to each bound row to highlight/un-higlight on mouse over/out. I have added an asp:button as a templatefield and bound a value to the CommandArgument. In IE and FIrefox I get the expected behaviour where the CommandName is passed to the _RowCommand event. However, when in Safari I only ever see the CommanName of "Select" passed to RowCommand.

The expected behaviour is that when a bound row is clicked the "Select" paramater is passed to the RowCommand event. When the Button in the row is clicked the argument "Remove" is passed.

```
protected void gvContacts_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onMouseOver", "Highlight(this)");
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onMouseOut", "UnHighlight(this)");

        e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(gvContacts, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);

        e.Row.Attributes["style"] = "cursor:pointer";
    }
}


protected void gvContacts_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{                

    switch (e.CommandName)  //Always "Select" when browser is Safari.  
    {
        case "Select":
            Session["clientID"] = gvContacts.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)].Cells[0].Text;
            Response.Redirect("../Contacts/ContactEdit.aspx?readin=1");
            break;
        case "Remove":
            //Remove the client from the list
            Company company = new Company();
            company.Get(Int32.Parse(Session["CompanyID"].ToString()), ((Model)Session["model"]).ConnectionString);
            company.RemoveUser(Int32.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString()));
            BindGrid(company.ID);
            break;
    }                
}
```

HTML for itemtemplate

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btnRemove" runat="server" Text="Remove" CommandName="Remove" OnClientClick="return confirmRemove();"
                                    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
   </ItemTemplate>
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: you gave command name "REMOVE" so how can row command event understand that button was clicked from safari and if it then you didn't mention the code for it...

Answer (score 0):

I think You should First Check that Button was clicked From which browser and if it was from safari than Change Command Name ..

```
  protected void gvContacts_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {                
    System.Web.HttpBrowserCapabilities browser = Request.Browser;
      if(browser.Browser=="Safari") //Check The Browser 
       {
          e.CommandName="Select";
       }
        switch (e.CommandName)  //Always "Select" when browser is Safari.  
        {
            case "Select":
                Session["clientID"] = gvContacts.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)].Cells[0].Text;
                Response.Redirect("../Contacts/ContactEdit.aspx?readin=1");
                break;
            case "Remove":
                //Remove the client from the list
                Company company = new Company();
                company.Get(Int32.Parse(Session["CompanyID"].ToString()), ((Model)Session["model"]).ConnectionString);
                company.RemoveUser(Int32.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString()));
                BindGrid(company.ID);
                break;
        }                
    }
```